# How to do WordPress Authentication?

Tags: php, wordpress, cordova, authentication

I am making cordova/phonegap project that is interacting with WP site. dealing with posts, comments .. etc.
I installed JSON REST API plugin for fetching posts from WP sites.
But some endpoints of JSON API required Authentication. such as ( create new post, create new comments.. )
But I don't know how to authenticate for wordpress site.
So I've read this [reference](https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/oauth2/).

What client_id is this?
How do I get this?

*client_id should be set to your application’s client ID as found in the applications manager*.

What's "my application"'s meaning?
Why does it authenticate from this URL instead of my domain?

https://public-api.wordpress.com/oauth2/authorize?

I am really confused.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I was also confused. But there is a better explanation here:
https://github.com/WP-API/api-console

Basically you need to run few lines on the server (Step 1), so Key and Secret will be your client_key and client_secret. If you'll finish what they say you can use them in the future.

Unfortunately I do not have opportunity to try it by myself because I don't have access to the server. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Although this may not exactly answer the question, it might provide a lead. I used xmlrpc to communicate to register and login both of which yield a WP userid.
Cordova code:

```
function register($uname, $pw, $email, $first, $last){
     ActivityIndicator.show("Registering");
     $.xmlrpc({
        url: 'http://www.yourwebsite.com/xmlrpc.php',
        methodName: 'gm.wp_create_user',
        params: ["0", $uname, $pw, $email, $first, $last, "ID", "PW"],   
        success: function(response, status, jqXHR) { 
           ActivityIndicator.hide();
           var num = parseInt(response[0]);
           if (!num){
              toast(response+', Please re-enter');
              return;
           }
           $.jStorage.set("usernum",num);
           $.jStorage.set("username",$uname);
           $.jStorage.set("password",$pw);
           $("#new-user").popup("close");
           //alert('success:'+response+" "+status+" "+jqXHR); 
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, status, error) { 
           ActivityIndicator.hide();
           $.jStorage.set("usernum",undefined);
           $("#new-user").popup("close");
        }
     });
  }
```

xmlrpc.php

```
    <?php
/**
 * XML-RPC protocol support for WordPress
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Whether this is an XML-RPC Request
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('XMLRPC_REQUEST', true);

// Some browser-embedded clients send cookies. We don't want them.
$_COOKIE = array();

// A bug in PHP < 5.2.2 makes $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA not set by default,
// but we can do it ourself.
if ( !isset( $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA ) ) {
    $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = file_get_contents( 'php://input' );
}

// fix for mozBlog and other cases where '<?xml' isn't on the very first line
if ( isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) )
    $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = trim($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);

/** Include the bootstrap for setting up WordPress environment */
include('./wp-load.php');

if ( isset( $_GET['rsd'] ) ) { // http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/blogs/gems/tech/rsd.html
header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=' . get_option('blog_charset'), true);
?>
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="'.get_option('blog_charset').'"?'.'>'; ?>
<rsd version="1.0" xmlns="http://archipelago.phrasewise.com/rsd">
  <service>
    <engineName>WordPress</engineName>
    <engineLink>http://wordpress.org/</engineLink>
    <homePageLink><?php bloginfo_rss('url') ?></homePageLink>
    <apis>
      <api name="WordPress" blogID="1" preferred="true" apiLink="<?php echo site_url('xmlrpc.php', 'rpc') ?>" />
      <api name="Movable Type" blogID="1" preferred="false" apiLink="<?php echo site_url('xmlrpc.php', 'rpc') ?>" />
      <api name="MetaWeblog" blogID="1" preferred="false" apiLink="<?php echo site_url('xmlrpc.php', 'rpc') ?>" />
      <api name="Blogger" blogID="1" preferred="false" apiLink="<?php echo site_url('xmlrpc.php', 'rpc') ?>" />
      <?php
          do_action( 'xmlrpc_rsd_apis' );
      ?>
    </apis>
  </service>
</rsd>
<?php
exit;
}

include_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php');
include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-IXR.php');
include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-xmlrpc-server.php');

/**
 * Posts submitted via the XML-RPC interface get that title
 * @name post_default_title
 * @var string
 */
$post_default_title = "";

/**
 * Filter the class used for handling XML-RPC requests.
     *
 * @since 3.1.0
 *
 * @param string $class The name of the XML-RPC server class.
 */
$wp_xmlrpc_server_class = apply_filters( 'wp_xmlrpc_server_class', 'wp_xmlrpc_server' );
$wp_xmlrpc_server = new $wp_xmlrpc_server_class;

// Fire off the request
$wp_xmlrpc_server->serve_request();

exit;

/**
 * logIO() - Writes logging info to a file.
 *
 * @deprecated 3.4.0
 * @deprecated Use error_log()
 *
 * @param string $io Whether input or output
 * @param string $msg Information describing logging reason.
 */
function logIO( $io, $msg ) {
    _deprecated_function( __FUNCTION__, '3.4', 'error_log()' );
    if ( ! empty( $GLOBALS['xmlrpc_logging'] ) )
    error_log( $io . ' - ' . $msg );
}
```

and in functions.php on wordpress child theme:

```
    add_filter( 'xmlrpc_methods', 'xml_add_method');
function xml_add_method( $methods ) {
    $methods['gm.wp_create_user'] = 'gm_wp_create_user';
    return $methods;
}

function gm_wp_create_user( $args ) {
    $uname = $args[1];
    $pword = $args[2];
    $email = $args[3];

    // Return Something
   $user_id = wp_create_user( $uname, $pword, $email ); 

   if( is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
    return $user_id->get_error_message();
    }
   else return $user_id;
   //return $blog_id.$username.$password.$uname.$pword.$email; 
}
```